# MYSQL - Count columns in a single row that contain the same data

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains 151 columns, with the first being the primary ID tied to a user.

The table's purpose is to track whether a person has accomplished a task, with there being 150 tasks. I will likely have thousands of persons having a unique row for their own task list.

The columns are populated with a value from 0 to 3, identifying the level of completion for each task.

I need to run a query that will clearly count the number of '3's in a specific row and produce a number. I will then take that number and divide it by 150 to give the specific player a completion percentage.

I will embed this query into a num_row query that displays all users in a list, with the above needed query count as one of the columns displayed.

I have previously got the following query to work on a page where there is no num_row list, however when I embed the query into the num_row list it only displays the first row out of hundreds.

where/what is my mistake?

```
$query9 = "SELECT * FROM ztnexus_ztnprints WHERE playerbp_id='$player_id' ";
$result9 = mysql_query($query9);
$numfields9 = mysql_num_fields($result9);
$row = 0;
for($i=0; $i < $numfields9; $i++){ if(mysql_result($result9, $row, $i) == '3'){ $name[$bpcount] = mysql_field_name($result9, $i); $bpcount++; } }
if (empty($bpcount)) { $bpcount = 0; }
$bp1 = ($bpcount / 150) ;
$bp2 =  number_format($bp1, 2) ;
$blueprints = ($bp2 * 100) ;
```

'$blueprints' is the desired percentage output.

Thank you.

****Edit****
I will add a visual example of my table:

```
FIELDS --->  | user_id  | task_1  | task_2  | task_3  | etc...  |
             ----------------------------------------------------
ROWS ----->  |    1     |   2     |    3    |    0    |   2     |
             |    20    |   3     |    2    |    3    |   1     |
             |    55    |   3     |    1    |    3    |   2     |
             ----------------------------------------------------
```

I need my query to count the threes for each user.

Comment: The num_row list works just fine, this query is embedded into the the repeated html table row so it queries for each user listed.

Comment: You wrote that this doesn't work "when I embed the query into the num_row list". So you need to show us that code if you want us to tell us where it's wrong.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the help but I ended up using a SUM( IF(column=3,1,NULL) + IF(column2=3,1,NULL)= etc....   I also figured out why my previous code conflicted with the numrow list, i had i=0; in the list query which conflicted with the for($i=0; $i < $numfields9; $i++) from the column count query. I just have to work it this way due to the fashion in which all tables tie together for my site. Again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your data model doesn't really fit what you are trying to accomplish, and it is fragile in the sense that adding tasks as the code evolves requires a data model change.

I would suggest instead creating a master/detail (or parent/child) table relationship.  Have one table that has player information, and another table with task completion information (one row per task per player, linked by the player ID).

This type of query then becomes a very simple query of the child table.

Comment: Thanks for replying, however you missed the fact that this is indeed a parent child model. This table holds nothing more than the task completion information. This table only holds the user ID number in the first column.

Comment: But it would be better to have a table with the columns UserID, TaskID, CompletionLevel rather than columns for each task.

Comment: @AesirValhallyn: I would have one row *per task*.  You have a 1:1 table relationship.  I am proposing 1:N.  Then, you would simply issue `SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM TaskTable WHERE user_id=$player_id AND task_stage=3`.

Comment: This would be great, however, on a separate page I mass update the user records with a num row input scheme. I could not do a mass update of these records using your recommended model.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help but I ended up using a

`SUM( IF(column=3,1,NULL) + IF(column2=3,1,NULL)=` etc....

I also figured out why my previous code conflicted with the numrow list, i had `i=0;` in the list query which conflicted with the

`for($i=0; $i < $numfields9; $i++)`

from the column count query.

I just have to work it this way due to the fashion in which all tables tie together for my site. Again, thanks for the help!